# Http Live Stream smooth running

Tags: android, multithreading, video

I am running an online stream, implementing the sample code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String httpLiveUrl = "......";

    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

As soon as the activity is loaded, a black screen appears and after a while the video is run. As I read in the documentation, it needs to be run on a different from the UI thread. However, when I add the run(), the video is not started at all. What is the approach here?

Comment: wheres the `run()` being called?

Comment: I tried doing it in onCreate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this to be much of a code issue needing threads.

```
the activity is loaded, a black screen appears and after a while the video is run.
```

This observation states that the video plays, but only after properly buffering enough content to start playback.

What you can do, is to give the app user an indication that the video is being buffered by usage of showing/hiding an image of your choice in your current layout and calling [`VideoView#setOnPreparedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener))

Here's an example of this:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String httpLiveUrl = "......";

videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // media file is loaded and ready to go.
        hideBufferingUi();
    }
});

videoView.requestFocus();
showBufferingUi();
videoView.start();
```

All that is left to implement here is

1. Pick an image
2. add it to your layout
3. add the `showBufferingUi` and `hideBufferingUi` methods

hths!

Comment: Oh, I did, but the vote is still not publicly visible, as my reputation is less than 15. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, I know this :) But my votes are not visible yet :)